# Error installing skype

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, skype

`enter code here`I got this wile doing the first step to installing skype on my comuputer-(saucy)

```
dj@localhost:~$ sudo apt-get install libqt4-dbus libqt4-network libqt4-xml libasound2
[sudo] password for dj: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libasound2 is already the newest version.
libqt4-dbus is already the newest version.
libqt4-network is already the newest version.
libqt4-xml is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libaudio2:i386 libavahi-client3:i386 libavahi-common-data:i386 libavahi-common3:i386 libcups2:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386
  libdrm-nouveau2:i386 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libelf1:i386 libffi6:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
  libglapi-mesa:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libgssapi-krb5-2:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386 libgstreamer0.10-0:i386
  libice6:i386 libk5crypto3:i386 libkeyutils1:i386 libkrb5-3:i386 libkrb5support0:i386 liblcms1:i386 libllvm3.3:i386
  libmng1:i386 libmysqlclient18:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386 libpciaccess0:i386 libqt4-dbus:i386 libqt4-declarative:i386
  libqt4-network:i386 libqt4-opengl:i386 libqt4-script:i386 libqt4-sql:i386 libqt4-sql-mysql:i386 libqt4-webkit:i386
  libqt4-xml:i386 libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 libqtcore4:i386 libqtgui4:i386 libqtwebkit4:i386 libsm6:i386
  libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386 libx11-xcb1:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-glx0:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxext6:i386 libxfixes3:i386
  libxi6:i386 libxml2:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxslt1.1:i386 libxss1:i386 libxt6:i386 libxv1:i386 libxxf86vm1:i386
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/85.8 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
dpkg: error processing libv4lconvert0:i386 (--configure):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libv4lconvert0:i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
(saucy)dj@localhost:~$
```

Comment: Try installing it from Ubuntu Software Center.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting instructions to take two actions:

Use

```
apt-get autoremove
```

to remove them.

So do a `sudo apt-get autoremove`. This isn't likely the root of your problem but it sure looks like your packages are a bit out of whack. Perhaps an install failed partway through and left garbage? Not sure but the autoremove seems to always just work for me so I suggest you do it.

And while you're at it, perhaps you should do a `sudo apt-get clean`. I don't think it will make a difference but if your cache is the source of bad data, this will fix it.

The second action is

```
dpkg: error processing libv4lconvert0:i386 (--configure):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration.
```

So try

```
sudo apt-get remove libv4lconvert0
sudo apt-get install libv4lconvert0
```

If that doesn't work, try again but use `purge` instead of `remove`.

I think this will fix the problem but I can't tell you what went wrong. I'm guessing an install broke and left config files in a bad way but it's a guess. If problems continue, I suggest a wipe and reinstall. I know that's a pain but it's pretty easy with Ubuntu and it fixes nearly all problems.